# Connection USB Android device to Windows computer

Tags: android, connection, usb

I am developing an android application and I want to connect the device to Windows computer and transfer data from my android application to another application running on the computer. Is it possible?
My minSdkVersion is 8.

Comment: In which mobile you are going to run your application?

Comment: My application will be available in google play so can run on any device. I read many similar questions that were not possible

Comment: I didn't got what you need exactly try to clarify your question?

Comment: My boss asked me to do data synchronization between two applications by USB. One application runs on an Android device and the other is a desktop application, but I think this is not possible.